# $\int \frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}\, dx$

Tags: integration

How would one go about integrating $\int  \frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}\, dx$

I tried rationalizing and then doing partial fractions but got something really ugly and IBP doesn't work too well either.

Comment: I edited your question. Is this the function you meant?

Comment: Yes sir, thank you so much!

Comment: In case you want to double check your answer, [check out](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+dx%2F(x%5E2+*+sqrt(x%5E2%2Bx%2B1))).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x=\dfrac1u$ then
\begin{align}
I
&= \int\dfrac{-u}{\sqrt{u^2+u+1}}du \\
&=  -\int\dfrac{2u+1}{2\sqrt{u^2+u+1}}du+\dfrac12\int\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{(u+\frac12)^2+\frac34}}du \\
&= -\sqrt{u^2+u+1}+\dfrac12\operatorname{arcsinh}\dfrac{2u+1}{\sqrt{3}}+C \\
&= -\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}{x}+\dfrac12\operatorname{arcsinh}\dfrac{x+2}{x\sqrt{3}}+C
\end{align}

Comment: The only sensible answer so far. +1

Comment: Yes, very nice! +1

Answer (score 3):

$x^2+x+1=\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}$.

Thus, the substitution $x+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\tan{t}$ must help.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$\int \frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}\, dx=\int \frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{(x+\frac12)^2+\frac34}}\, dx$

Now substitute $u=x+\frac12$